# Lighthouse metrics wrong

Tags: lighthouse

I've got 0 performance-wise after running Lighthouse. I checked the metrics and here's what I saw:

```
First Contentful Paint 20.8 s
Speed Index 33.9 s
Time to Interactive 94.1 s
First Meaningful Paint 20.8 s
First CPU Idle 20.8 s
Max Potential First Input Delay 2,840 ms
```

But these metrics are absolutely wrong, *the whole lighthouse check ran for 13s.* How can it have measured that the first contentful paint was 20s in ??

Any idea why this would happen ? I'm running lighthouse in my Chrome dev tool. This is running on a netlify cdn website (protected with htaccess so maybe that's why ? Although I got the same problem running lighthouse in localhost)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you share the url?

Comment: I'm also getting this... did you ever find out the reason?

Answer (score 1):

By default, Lighthouse loads the page with the host network speed and CPU, and in a post-processing step does a simulation on a simplified model of the page load with slower network/CPU applied. See https://github.com/GoogleChrome/lighthouse/blob/master/docs/throttling.md

There are options to disable this throttling in the CLI and in DevTools.